# public object の使い方

Tags: android, java, android-studio, kotlin

public object User （class Objectでしょうか？）の

fun addBookmark(identifier: Int) メソッドを実行したいのですが、
エラーが出てしまいます。

```
int aaa = 1111111;
User.addBookmark(aaa);
```

non static method addBookmark(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

解決方法を教えてください。

Comment: Userクラスがmypackageクラスにないか、Userクラスのデフォルトコンストラクタが利用できないようprivate化されているのではないでしょうか。Userクラスのインスタンスを使う場合、引数を渡す必要があるのではないかと思いますが、Userクラスも提示していただくと、明確な回答がつきやすいと思います。

Comment: 前の質問の問題が解決されていないのならば、その質問で続行するべきで、改めて同じ内容を問う質問を別途ポストしないでください。

Comment: エラーからして違う内容なので、別に立てました。

Comment: 何故同じ内容なのか説明をいただけたら助かります。

Comment: どうも状況がよく分からないのですが、kotlin オブジェクトのメソッドを呼び出すのであれば、Java コードではなく、kotlin コードで `val aaa: Int = 1111111; User.addBookmark(aaa);` とでも書けば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @makki `'User()'is not public in　『mypackage』 cannot be accessed from outside package`このエラーについてです。もし、今回の質問で、このエラーは関係がないのなら、紛らわしいので記載は避けてください。（適切に修正していただければ、再オープンの対象となりうると思いますので、適宜、柔軟に対応していただければと思います）

Comment: わかりました。削除しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

『non static method addBookmark(int) cannot be referenced from a static context』
こちらは英文の通り、「非staticメソッドであるaddBookmark(int)はstatic参照できない」というエラーです。
非staticメソッドはインスタンスから呼び出さなくてはならないため、

```
User.addBookmark(aaa);
```

のように「クラス名.メソッド名」の記述では上記のエラーが発生します。
まずはUserクラスのインスタンスを作成し、作成したインスタンスからaddBookmark()メソッドを実行してください。

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.addBookmark(aaa);
```

なお、staticメソッド／非staticメソッドの違いは長くなるため言及しませんが、今回の問題を解決するためには(さらにはJavaを扱う上で)必須となる知識ですので、その点の理解が不足しているようでしたらご自身で調べてみてください。